# Is there any room for JQuery in a JSF based web architecture?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

JSF architecture is very component based. Click a button you end up somewhere on the server.  JSF hides the HTTP requests between the button and your listetener, trying to make your code look like Swing.  I guess this means you can end up with a lot HTTP requests even if they are hidden from you.

JQuery, Javascript means you can make things fatter on the client and cut down on http requests.  You can set up way more even handling logic to happen completly client side -  and because JQuery has such a rich set of libraries e.g. JQuery UI, you can do quite a lot in a fat client without ever having to go to server.

So I am wondering once you go down the JSF path (rightly or wrongly) would you ever end up using Jquery much?  Or have you already made the decsisions that you're going to keeping things thin on the client and not using much javascript or any of the popular javascript libraries.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has a room in every web application. The two most popular JSF components Richfaces and Primefaces contain reusable components that are built on top jQuery and third party jQuery plugins.

Comment: thanks.  But if there are built ontop of JQuery, does that mean a developer would be using JQuery API's or not?  I.e. is the JQuery stuff encapsulated away or what?  Thanks.

Comment: If you're using such components then you're implicitly using jQuery behind the scene.